# Algorithm: How to space new elements in fixed length circular array as far away from existing elements as possible?

Tags: algorithm

I'd like to space elements as far away from each other as possible.

Let’s say the array has length 360.

```
Element 1 goes at position 0.
Element 2 goes at position 180.
Element 3 goes at position 90 (or 270).
Element 4 goes at position 270 (or 90).
Element 5 goes at position 45.
Element 6 goes at position 135.
Element 7 goes at position 225.
Element 8 goes at position 315.
Element 9 goes at position 23.
Element 10 goes at position 68.
```

And so forth.

Let's say the length is 100.

```
Element 1 goes at position 0.
Element 2 goes at position 50.
Element 3 goes at position 25 (or 75).
Element 4 goes at position 75 (or 72).
Element 5 goes at position 13.
Element 6 goes at position 38 (or 75).
Element 7 goes at position 63.
```

And so forth.

The user would pass in an array length and the element number. So f(2,360) would return 180 and f(7,100) would return 63.

What's the method to output the position given an array length and element number?

EDIT: My specific application is that I am trying to choose colors of different hue for every element, equally spaced, before I know how many elements there will be.

EDIT 2: My problem statement caused some confusion. I used integers in my demo solutions for simplicity, when I didn't actually want integer output. My mistake. I'll mark the solution that accounts for this as correct, though I should caveat that I have not checked it myself. My answer below I have checked and it works, though it's 0 indexed and returns decimals.

Comment: I dont't think you should say array of length 360, its confusing

Comment: also what do you mean by far away from each other, do you want to maximize the minimum distance ( in terms of angle ) ?

Comment: You should give a more precise problem statement. As of now, it is not clear.

Comment: I provided an example for a different length array.

Comment: What's the pseudo code to output the position given the element number and array length?

Comment: It looks like your method is pretty simple. On a 0-1 scale, you place one at zero. Then for each n starting at 1 and counting up, you place one at k/2^n for odd k, where 1<=k<=2^n. Just multiply by m to get it on a 0-m scale instead.

Comment: It might be easier to just put everything in a list to start with, and calculate the gap between elements (and the placement as well, if necessary) only after you know your list is complete, and so you have the actual number of items available to assist in the computation.

Comment: I think you can get close by using a recursive algorithm, which cuts the interval passed in half and calls itself with one of the halves, depending on what the index you are calculating is. Let me know if you don't get what I mean and I'll try to elaborate, though this is just off the top of my head at the moment.

Comment: Bizarre requirement.  You are almost certainly overlooking the considerable problem of how to make this work while code is also reading from the queue.  And will of course hit an element it shouldn't read because you didn't write it yet.  That can't work, you have to prevent reading.  Which disconnects the problem from the queue completely, you just rearrange the items before you add them ;-p

Comment: @HansPassant I may be misunderstanding your comment, but it doesn't seem that a queue is necessary. Each value can be calculated independently.

Comment: Added solution for Edits 1 & 2. Most of the arithmetic is replaced by bit operations. Sorry to nit-pick, but though you said your "answer below I have checked and it works, though it's 0 indexed and returns decimals" except that it doesn't work with step=0.

Comment: Don't apologize for nit-picking! Good catch. I've updated my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a non-recursive solution without repetitions, as long as `0 < i <= n`. It was written in as a language-agnostic way as possible so if you don't know ruby it shouldn't matter:

```rb
# round, but if fraction is .5 then floor.
def round2 x
  double = 2*x
  double == double.round ? x.floor : x.round
end

# i is 1-based. 0 < n.
def f( i, n )
  j = (i-1) % n # convert to 0-based and mod n index j
  nsig = 1 << Math.log2(n).floor # highest bit in n
  if (j&nsig) == 0
    j2 = 1 << Math.log2((j<<1)|1).floor # smallest power of 2 > j
    angle = n*(j2^((j<<1)|1)) / j2.to_f # to_f converts to float
    return angle.round
  else
    return round2(n*((nsig^j)+0.5)/(nsig^n))
  end
end

[360,100].each do |n|
  puts "\nFor array length #{n}:\n"
  (1..12).each do |i|
    puts 'Element %d goes to position %d.' % [ i, f(i,n) ]
  end
end
```

Output:

```
For array length 360:
Element 1 goes to position 0.
Element 2 goes to position 180.
Element 3 goes to position 90.
Element 4 goes to position 270.
Element 5 goes to position 45.
Element 6 goes to position 135.
Element 7 goes to position 225.
Element 8 goes to position 315.
Element 9 goes to position 23.
Element 10 goes to position 68.
Element 11 goes to position 113.
Element 12 goes to position 158.

For array length 100:
Element 1 goes to position 0.
Element 2 goes to position 50.
Element 3 goes to position 25.
Element 4 goes to position 75.
Element 5 goes to position 13.
Element 6 goes to position 38.
Element 7 goes to position 63.
Element 8 goes to position 88.
Element 9 goes to position 6.
Element 10 goes to position 19.
Element 11 goes to position 31.
Element 12 goes to position 44.
```

Basic idea is to visualize the placement of items around a circle. If you look at the bits of the 0-based index then you can quickly see a pattern between the length in bits of the index, and where they are placed around the circle.

For example, elements 5, 6, 7, 8 are placed as follows. First, subtract 1 to make them 0-based, and observe the bits:

```
4: 100
5: 101
6: 110
7: 111
```

These are all of the indices with length-3 (in bit size). These are placed at the 45°, 135°, 225°, 315° locations around the circle. Then it is just arithmetic and rounding to convert to indices within the circular array.

Here's a version in JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/gfj7Lpya/3/

---

For OP Edits 1 & 2, in JavaScript:

```js
// i is 0-based. Return value in [0,1).
function f( i )
{
  if( i === 0 ) return 0;
  var ndigits = Math.floor(Math.log(i)/Math.LN2); // in base 2
  return ((1<<ndigits^i)<<1|1) / (2<<ndigits);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfj7Lpya/4/

To apply this to an array "length" of 360, for example, just multiply the output:

```js
360 * f(8) // 22.5
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong: (0...360).map{|i|f(i, 360)}.uniq.length

Comment: @JuanLopes Fixed. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 2):

Phil's solution got me thinking. I think this is slightly better as it only requires one log. In JavaScript:

```
// Returns the position of element n
// as far away as possible from other elements
// with total space totalSpace
function getPlacement(n, totalSpace) {
    if (n == 0) return 0;

    var divisions = Math.pow(2, log2Floor(n) + 1);
    var position = ((2 * (n + 1 - (divisions / 2))) - 1);
    return position * ( totalSpace / divisions );
}

// Quickly returns the floor of the base 2 log
function log2Floor(x) {
  if (x === 0) return -Infinity;
  for (var i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    if (x >>> i === 1) return i;
  }
}
```

Comment: In general this approach seems to work up until the highest power of 2 less than the length of the array. For 360, this works for `step <= 256`. This is what Juan Lopes called me out on. For the remaining entries, you have to use a different algorithm to avoid collisions. This is the reason for the `else` clause in my answer.

Comment: Woah, will investigate tonight when I get home. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: My method works for all values of step where length = 10. I also checked for step = 257 and length = 360 and it returned the proper result (2.109375) Can you provide a case where length is relatively small and my method doesn't work?

Comment: First off, your step is off by 1. Assuming that is corrected, `f(257,360)=0.703125`. Compare this with `f(129,360)=1.40625` and `f(1,360)=0`. However you decide to round the first two, there is going to be a collision here. Sure, you're not going to have collisions if you don't return integers, but you have solved a different problem than originally stated. As your question was stated, f must return an integer. For length=10, `1 -> 0` and `5 -> 1` (from 1.25). `9 -> 0.625`. Is that 0 or 1? Collision either way.

Comment: My error was in my problem statement. I don't need integer output (indeed I prefer decimals) and the 1 indexing was for ease in demonstrating the problem. I'm not sure what the right thing to do now is. I could restate it to fit my solution or I could mark your answer as correct. The problem with the latter is that it requires a few extra bounds (integer only, 1 indexing) that probably aren't very useful in the wild. Thoughts?

Comment: The comments, and at least one solution (mine) are referencing the current problem as stated, so for continuity I would think it would make the most sense to choose an answer to *that* question rather than to fundamentally change the question. The "integer only" requirement is deduced by the fact that you are putting elements into a circular array, so naturally the indices are integers. This is also inferred from the example "Element 9 goes at position 23" rather than 22.5. If you want to add an addendum to change the step value from 1-based to 0-based that is fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

This function you are looking for, let's call it `f(i,n)`, can be defined recursively as follows (assuming indexing starts from 0, and `log(x)` outputs the floor of the base 2 log of `x`):

```
f(0,n)=0
f(1,n)=n/2
if(i%2==0){
   f(i,n)=f(i/2,n)-f(2^(log(i)-1),n)/2
}
else{
   f(i,n)=f(i/2,n)+f(2^(log(i)-1),n)/2
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Implemented your solution and it doesn't seem to work: https://gist.github.com/juanplopes/aabf64c52d87d3adc933

Comment: Updated my solution, should work now. I apologize for the mistake, only tested for the first 8 indices!

Comment: Thanks Phil! Loved the simplicity here.